# How do I print 1 to 10 in netbeans and print odd and even numbers?

Tags: java, netbeans

imprimir del 1 al 10 en neat beans 
tambien necesito los numeros pares
y impares gracias!!!!.

> **Spanish to English Translation**
>
> **Question Title:** how to print 1 to 10 in net beans and print odd and even
>   numbers thanks for your answers
>
> **Question Text:** print 1 to 10 in neat beans also need the even and odd
>   numbers thanks !!!!.

Comment: Please try it and post some code. (Por favor, inténtelo y después de algún código.)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Note that this site is in English, please edit your question into English. Also, show us what you tried in solving the problem, and what happened differently than you expected.

Comment: English if you please, if you want any help. Love it or not but english is the lingua franca of computer science. This is your first post so I don't mark it down.

Comment: Guidelines for non-English content: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/8239061

Answer (score 1):

**En Espanol:**

```
// recorrer todos los números del 1 al 10
for(int i=0; i <=10; i++){
  if( i%2 == 0 ) // modulo prueba por pares o impares
    System.out.println ( i + " es pares");
  else
    System.out.println ( i + " es impares");
}
```

¿Es esto lo que querías?

**In English:**

```
// loop through all the numbers 1 to 10
for(int i=0; i <=10; i++){
  if( i%2 == 0 ) // modulo test for even or odd
    System.out.println ( i + " is even");
  else
    System.out.println ( i + " is odd");
}
```

Is this what you're asking for?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Note that this site is in English, please edit your answer into English. See also the SO blog: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: @Piskvor : Thanks for the policy update. Last I checked Meta, the multilingual issue was up in the air. I added English translations.

Comment: Alas, for some reason I can't find it explicitly mentioned on Meta, only on the blog (which is not too integrated with the rest of the site). Thanks for the edit.

Comment: if you've understood the question, could you take the time to translate it for us, please?

Comment: Google Translate works really well, even if you don't understand Spanish : )

Comment: Community preference is to avoid using Google Translate on others' content. 
 See Guidelines for non-English content: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/8239061

Comment: @rlb.usa No problem. My intent was not to be "nitty-gritty" but post relevant guidelines that govern the site moderation. For the record, I did not downvote or flag this Q/A. Thanks for your perspective.